# Can not "brew install postgresql"

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I cannot install postgresql with homebrew.

```
$ brew install postgresql
Error: Could not create /usr/local/Cellar
Check you have permission to write to /usr/local
```

I am not sure if homebrew was installed well. If you need more information, I will update this.

Comment: @JunichiIto please post this resolution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created /usr/local/Cellar by myself, then could install successfully.

Comment: this shouldn't be the answer for all cases. for example in my case i added /usr/local/var/log/mongodb after getting error, then was presented with a new error: Error: File exists - /usr/local/var/log/mongodb

Comment: brew should have created the Cellar directory for you, I would uninstall brew and start over

Answer (score 8):

I find that if I get this problem with brew I just fix the permissions on the `/use/local` folder:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

Comment: I got an error message says `chown: illegal option -- m`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error while installation that not able to link postgres and /usr/local/include is not writable

**Below solution worked for me :-**
First create the include folder, note that this requires sudo privileges

```
cd /usr/local

sudo mkdir include

sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

brew link postgresql
```